# Can I get a parameter from shortened URL through an Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have shortened URL's scanned from QRCODES.
The full URL has some parameters that I need.

I'm putting up an Iframe to load the shortened URL and was hoping to get the "full" url once it loaded.

But didn't get to work...

Is it possible?

Once the Iframe is loaded, I try access it using:

`iframe.contentWindow.location.href`

But always get an error

`ERROR DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8100" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: localhost is sometimes limited for security reasons. If both host and iframe window are from same domain, it would probably work, but there is another way.

Comment: You could use `Window.fetch` api to get the URL it redirects to.

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions to the communication between iframe and host if you control the content of both windows, but they often feel like hacks and can be limiting.

For a general solution, you could get the redirected URL before you even load the iframe.

The fetch api has a "redirect" option you can set to "manual" to get the URL it redirects to.

```
fetch(shorturl, {redirect: "manual"})
   .then(function(response) {
       var iframeurl;
       if (response.type==="opaqueredirect") {
           // set to redirected url
           iframeurl = response.url
       }
       else {
           // use original url.
           iframeurl = shorturl
       }
       iframe.contentWindow.location.href = iframeurl;
       handleQueryString(iframeurl)


   })
```